# Javascript forEach not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, for-loop

My goal is to iterate through an array of results and do stuff with the data but for some reason I can't get the foreach loop in javascript to work, I can't seem to make any sort of enumeration work.

Here's my test

```
console.debug("I got this far.");
for(var i=0;i< results.length; i++){
    console.debug("Worked.");
}
console.debug("Past.");
console.debug(results);
```

I have also tried

```
results.forEach(function(x) { console.debug("Worked"); });
```

and

```
for(var x in results)
```

None seem to be working, is there something I'm doing wrong?

The output for the above is

```
I got this far.  query.html:39
Past.            query.html:40
[ Object , Object , Object , Object , Object , Object , Object , Object , Object , Object ]
```

So I know that the results variable is the right type but it is just not iterating.  There is another place where the forEach() works just fine but here it's not, any suggestions on how to debug and address this would be helpful.

full code (WORKING SOLUTION)

```
var table;
var request = { query : { match_all : {}}};
var map;
function initialize(results) {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.4, -71.3),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        myOptions);
    results.forEach(function(x) {
      var markerLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(x.location.lat, x.location.lon);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: markerLoc,
        map: map,
        title: "Hello World!"
        });
      });

};
$(document).ready(function() {
        var results = [];
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:9200/devices/devices/_search",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(request),
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function(x) {
                if ( x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                    x.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");

                    }
            },
            success: function(data) { 
                data.hits.hits.forEach(function(x) { results.push(x._source); } );
                initialize(results);
            }

        });

});
```

Comment: What is `results`? What value does `results.length` have? How is it populated?

Comment: Just wondering if `I got this far` is at line 39, how `Past.` is at line 40.

Comment: @Quentin: looks like `var results = Object.create( Array.prototype );`

Comment: What browser and please show us the code for declaring and defining the `results` variable?

Comment: ^ Chrome.  So I added a console.debug(results.length) and it's 0!?  Which makes sense now why the iteration isn't working but why is results a proper array in the debug and not in this scope.

Comment: Please show us a *complete*, working test case rather than bitty fragments. A link to a jsfiddle will do.

Comment: @lukecampbell — Because you created it using an array prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `results` to `initialize` as soon as the Ajax request *has been sent*. You aren't waiting for the response to come back, so the code that populates it doesn't fire until too late.

Move the call to `initialize` so it is inside the `success` handler.

Comment: You sir are my hero of the day.